# How to convert text to JSON in JavaScript

Tags: formatter

My dataset looks like the below:

```
Make: AUSTIN
Models:
1000
1300
Make: Ferrari
Models:
458
La Ferrari
```

I will like this in a JSON format, as below:

```
{
    make: "AUSTIN",
    models:          [
        {model:  "1000"},
        {model:  "1300"}
    ]
},
{
    make: "Ferrari",
    models:          [
        {model:  "458"},
        {model:  "La Ferrari"}
    ]
}
```

It's a very large dataset so I can't do it manually.

Looked around online and didn't find anything suitable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In which language u need..java or javascript?

Comment: JavaScript. I will update my question. Sorry I forgot

Comment: Use the JavaScript function JSON.parse() to convert text into a JavaScript object:

Imagine we received this text from a web server:
'{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');

Comment: It doesn't I'm afraid. The format of my text right now isn't JSON friendly. If it was, then I wouldn't need to transform it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, I would like to answer it.

You can do something like this.

```
function getFormatted(s){
   const total = []
   const lines = s.split('\n');
   let index = 0;
   while(lines[index]){
     const make = lines[index];
     const obj = {
            make: make.replace('Make: ',''),
            models: []
     }

     // index + 1 will be 'Models:'
    
     let modelCurrentIndex = index + 2;
     let currentModel = lines[modelCurrentIndex];

     // Check until the next occurrence of 'Make: '

     while(currentModel && !currentModel.startsWith("Make:")){
            obj.models.push({model: currentModel});
            modelCurrentIndex += 1;
            currentModel = lines[modelCurrentIndex];
    }
    index = modelCurrentIndex;
    total.push(obj);
   } 
   return JSON.stringify(total);
}
```

Sample Web Page would be like this 
[image]

After calling this function,
[image]

**Explanation:**

The First Index of the lines should be identified as 'make' and that index + 2 will be identified as the starting point of Models.
The while loop will add the models to the array in the object until it identifies the line that starts with 'Make:'.
 After that, the index is moved and the process gets repeated.

> Make sure you are entering the values with a line break!

Comment: Awesome mate! I will give this a go shortly before accepting the answer. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Sure! You're welcome.  https://jsfiddle.net/kqdfvbsc/

Comment: How did you figure out that the 2nd AUSTIN was a make? Couldn't figure that one out from the code. Thanks

Comment: It didn't work on my dataset. I was asking how you figured out the 2nd AUSTIN for a new car make? Thanks

Comment: The edited answer too didn't suit your case? 
The 2nd AUSTIN is identified by checking whether the line is a number. If it is a number, add it to the model array. else then it is the next car make.

Comment: Oh got it. I will work with this and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Hey Shri. Thanks again for your help but it doesn't work. I will edit my dataset in the question to include "make:" in the bit that goes to Make and all else goes to Models. The models doesn't need to be in number format for example: La Ferrari

Comment: It made me sad seeing the answer downvoted after so much effort, so I upvoted just for this reason

Comment: Thank You so much! @CristianTraìna

Comment: @ShayanKhan Now I modified my answer. Is it correct now? Now, the 2nd AUSTIN is identified by checking whether the line starts with 'Make:'. If it is so, break the loop and move to the next line.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I’ll get back to you soon. Really appreciate it!

Comment: That did it! One minor issue is that the Make, if with a space, gets truncated but I can fix that. Thanks a ton for helping out man! I had no idea how to go about it!

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah! I didn't notice that you could do `make.replace('Make: ',' ')` Happy Coding!